# How to get total number of records in query result in SQL after slicing in python

Tags: python, sql

I have 10 records:

Query Like: `result = select * from employee`
Here I got 10 records. Then applying slicing on those records to show as per my requirement

```
r = result[1:3]
```

I showing 3 records from index 0 to 2. Here I want to count the number of records r variable contains exactly. At the end I am applying slicing as [9:12]. But it contains only 1 record at the end. So how I can get exact number of records after slicing done to my result set.

I tried with below:

```
count = r.count()
```

Then got the error like below:

> AttributeError: 'long' object has no attribute 'count'

Any help help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Note that `result[1:3]` is giving a list with *two* records with index 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the builtin function [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len):

```
len(r)
```